# LinearLayout nested in ContraintLayout, And LinearLayout's orientation is horizontal, LinearLayout became visible, the Constraint is invalid

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I want to make a itemView in RecyclerView, and it show delete button when long clicked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/codeTv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/deleteCl"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/deleteLl"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and in adapter ：

```
itemView = CallingItemView(parent.context).apply {
    layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )
    setOnLongClickListener {
       if (this.deleteCl.visibility == VISIBLE) {
           this.deleteCl?.visibility = GONE
       } else {
           this.deleteCl?.visibility = VISIBLE
       }
       true
    }
}
```

Long Click:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm6XE.png]

and，if we change linearLayout orientation to vertical, it show:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/24iMG.png]

Why the constraintLayout 's Constraint invalid?

if replace ConstraintLayout id/deleteCl to RelativeLayout, the view is normal

Comment: What do you want exactly where your view should be?

Comment: below  image， the button is center in parent layout

Comment: Your example is working correctly. Could you post complete layout?

Comment: code is working fine byy the way

Comment: in the recyclerView, layoutManager is GridLayoutManager(context, 4)

Comment: Why you're using 2 ConstraintLayout and 1 LinearLayout? You can do the same thing with just only 1 ConstraintLayout. Your second ConstraintLayout has same width and height with parent (you can set parent's background instead of second ConstraintLayout) and also TextView has same width and height with LinearLayout (you can set TextView''s background instead of LinearLayout).

Comment: because out ConstraintLayout is xml root layout, when i long click it, it show the delete layer,  the delete layer have a small button